# Why was Turkey neutral during WWII?

Tags: world-war-two

After loosing a large part of its land on the Balkans and in the Middle East the newly found <sup>in 1923</sup> successor of the Ottoman Empire had every reason to  try and take back some of the lost nearby lands.

I understand that there were a series of conflicts and wars in the region: uprisings and revolts related to Greek Independence <sup>1821</sup> and Bulgarian Independence <sup>1878(1908)</sup>, Greco-Turkish War <sup>1897</sup> , First and Second Balkan Wars <sup>1912-1913</sup>, WWI<sup>1914-1918</sup>.

However, the much smaller neighbouring countries participated in WWII, while Turkey remained neutral.

What were (could be) the reasons for the Turkish neutrality during the Second World War?

Comment: Which side could they've joined? It's not like the World War was a free for all. The rest of the Balkan states were too small to really have a choice. Turkey was big enough to not worth the trouble, but too weak to really cause any trouble.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technicaly, Turkey participated: it entered the war on the Allies side on February 23, 1945, after a substantial allied pressure.

Why it did not participate earlier, I think it is easy to answer.
You "profit" from a world war only if you take the right side.
In WWI Turkey (reluctantly) chose the wrong side, and the result was the collapse of the empire. Telling early which side is going to win was difficult, in both world wars.

As I understand, after the collapse, the point of view prevailed that Turkey has
to be a national state rather than empire (the Russians do not understand it even now). Therefore, it did not really want to try to restore the empire, preferring to stay neutral.

It seems that empires are out of date since the second half of 20s century.

EDIT:...at least in Europe and in the Middle East.

Comment: re "*It seems that empires are out of date since the second half of 20s century*": Except for Russia, China, India, Pakistan and Eurozone, it's possible that you are right. That leaves perhaps 50% of the world's population for which your statement applies.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens what about the Common Wealth Nations and the US? Is there status different ?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: I simply saw the U.S. as less obviously an *empire*; and perhaps better thought of as just a *federation*. This is clearly arguable for the other side.  The Commonwealth is really just an excuse for *world-class but not world-wide* sports events due to shared history; it makes no pretense at any sort of actual governance.

Comment: Well, the Commonwealth have some agreements regarding security issues and trade cooperation and they all _bow to the queen_. In addition there are still many places around the world held under a strange political status: the Gibraltar, for example and many other islands of strategic location. As for the US with military bases all around the world and direct action in almost every political or military "happening" around the world (through EU and NATO), I don't know if there was any other country matching the definition of empire better than it :)

Comment: @Pieter Geerkins: I agree about Russia, not so sure about China, and strongly disagree about Eurozone (not even speaking of the US and Commonwealth). Probably our definitions of "empires" are different. Perhaps 50% do live in the empires, but still I think they are out of fashion. The general trend on my opinion is away from empires and towards the nation-states.

Comment: @Pieter Gerkins: in 1870, 50% of the Earth population worked in agriculture, but this was not the trend.

Comment: `The general trend on my opinion is away from empires and towards the nation-states` The creation of Eurozone is an obvious counter-example to your opinion. But it's quite logical that you think the empires are to go, as long as you can't see that new empires are to be founded.

Comment: @Matt: Eurozone is not am empire. I do not want to argue about terminology, but is not it clear that Ottoman, Russian and Austro-Hungarian and British empires are something very different from Eurozone?

Comment: @Alex Eurozone is an heir of German Empire, not Ottoman or British.

Comment: @Matt: Which German empire? First, Second or Third?

Comment: @Alex Basically, Deutsches Kaiserreich.

Comment: @Matt: Why not of the Third Reich? The main difference between the Eurozone and the previous empires is that neighboring countries want to join very much. If you do not believe me, ask the Turks, Ukrainians and Moldavians (all other neighbors already joined). Or will you argue that they were invaded?

Comment: @Alex Is this your best argument?! Even Roman empire had foederati and socii. It seems your understanding of empires is vague.

Comment: @Matt: This is not the place to discuss definitions. The original question was about Ottoman empire...